# Logo not displaying in React when wrapped with the link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header

I am trying to create an header in react, once I wrap it in the `Link` tag, the logo doesn't show. Once I remove the link, the logo shows. This is my code. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../logo.svg';


export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark px-sm-5">
            <Link to="/">
                <img src={logo} alt="store"/>
            </Link>

            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is weird, it works in both cases on my end, just tested.

Comment: wow, very weird

Comment: [Works for me too](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wiles-jthbm).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is particular to the image, i tried 2 other svgs and 2 pngs', 1 out of the svgs' did not display , the other images displayed. Thanks guys for your input.
so when this happens to any other person, the problem might be with the image.